# Python not creating file when ran from cmd line

Tags: python, cmd

I have a create a python script to clean a csv file. code in the script file "CleanCSV.py" as below

```
import csv

filepath_i = 'C:\Source Files\Data Source\Flat File Source\PatientRecords.csv'
filepath_o = 'C:\Python\PatientRecords.csv'
rows = []
with open(filepath_i, 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    with open(filepath_o, 'w', newline='' ) as writeFile:
        writer = csv.writer(writeFile, lineterminator='\r')
        for row in csv_reader:
            row[3] = row[3].replace("\n","").replace("\r","") 
            rows.append(row) 
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

This is working fine when ran from python editor. but not creating file when ran from command line like below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>python C:\Python\CleanCSV.py
```

I tried this as well

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64>pythonw C:\Python\CleanCSV.pyw
```

I provided full access to folder but still its not creating any file at destination. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Also please suggest if this code can be optimized. I can't use external packages like pandas so I did it with csv. Thanks in advance.

> Extension

When I changed to x for write setting

```
with open(filepath_o, 'x', newline='' ) as writeFile:
```

to my surprise I got this error

```
File "CleanCSV.py", line 8, in <module>
    with open(filepath_o, 'x', newline='' ) as writeFile:
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'C:\\Python\\PatientRecords1.csv'
```

but I don't see the file in the directory. even after setting hidden files to true. So I ran this script.

```
from pathlib import Path
config = Path(filepath_o )
if config.is_file():
    print('yes')
    print(config)
else:
    print('no')
```

got this ouptut, but there is no file in the directory!! puzzled.

```
yes
C:\Python\PatientRecords1.csv
```

> Extension 2

Rewrote script to try with directories

```
with open(filepath_i,'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    with open('PatientRecords1.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
        fieldnames = ['DRG Definition','Provider Id','Provider Name','Provider Street Address','Provider City','Provider State','Provider Zip Code','Hospital Referral Region Description','Hospital Category','Hospital Type', 'Total Discharges' ,'Covered Charges' , 'Total Payments' ,'Medicare Payments']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(writeFile,fieldnames=fieldnames)
        for row in csv_reader:
            row['Provider Street Address'] = row['Provider Street Address'].replace("\n","").replace("\r","") 
            writer.writerows(row)
```

But received this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CleanCSV.py", line 36, in <module>
    writer.writerows(row)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\csv.py", line 158, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Sample input file data

```
DRG Definition,Provider Id,Provider Name,Provider Street Address,Provider City,Provider State,Provider Zip Code,Hospital Referral Region Description,Hospital Category,Hospital Type, Total Discharges ,Covered Charges , Total Payments ,Medicare Payments
039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC,10001,SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER,1108 ROSS CLARK CIRCLE,DOTHAN,AL,36301,AL - Dothan,Specialty Centers,Government Funded,91,"$32,963.07 ","$5,777.24 ","$4,763.73 "
039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC,10005,MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH,"2505 U S HIGHWAY 
431 NORTH",BOAZ,AL,35957,AL - Birmingham,Specialty Centers,Private Institution,14,"$15,131.85 ","$5,787.57 ","$4,976.71 "
039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC,10006,ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL,205 MARENGO STREET,FLORENCE,AL,35631,AL - Birmingham,Rehabilitation Centers,Private Institution,24,"$37,560.37 ","$5,434.95 ","$4,453.79 "
```

> Extension 3

Looks like file is created in the directory, I got output for this two peices of code. However I am unable to see that file, wondering why!!

```
with open(filepath_o,'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)

import os.path 
from os import path
print(path.exists(filepath_o ))
```

Comment: Why are you running from the Python install directory? Run from the actual script location. Make sure you've added Python to your PATH

Comment: should I copy python.exe to script file location 'C:\Python\PatientRecords.csv'.

Comment: No, follow this: https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/. This will allow you to run Python from anywhere

Comment: Once you get past your PATH problems, if you append the extensions .py and .pyw to the PATHEXT environment variable using ; as a separator (assuming they are not already there), you are stating that these file types should be considered executable. You should than be able to execute a python file as in the the second case you tried above (i.e. just entering the file name without preceding it with the python command) or double-clicking on a python file it within an explorer window. For this to work, of course, there must be an association between these file types and  their "openers".

Comment: sure will do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the location where your python script is present. Click on the address bar of folder and type **cmd**

Then the command prompt will be launched from the script's folder location

then type in cmd

```
python CleanCSV.py
```

*NOTE* : You need to have python added to environment variable.

---

If you're using Anaconda, follow the same above mentioned steps from Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: I did this, added env variable to python.exe path and executed from script location. but it didn't create file..

Comment: Please look into my edit. It says file exists but I don't see the file.

Comment: import os os.listdir() Does the filename shows up ?

Comment: yes, it is showing up. even print is working on that file. please see the 3rd ext to my question for code.

Comment: this is the output I got ['CleanCSV.py', 'PatientRecords.csv']

Comment: That's actually very weird. It should show ideally. Can you see PatientRecords.csv ?

Answer (score 0):

That is puzzling. `csv` might not like your explicit r/w/x arguments in `open`. For example, instead of using `open(filepath_i, 'r', newline='')`, try `open(filepath_i, newline='')`.

Comment: thanks, I tried and got this error.   File "CleanCSV.py", line 13, in <module>
    writer.writerows(rows)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable